Visualization of Weighted Graph with NetworkX and Matplotlib: Addressing Node Overlapping Issue
I am visualizing a graph where each pair of nodes connected by a comma represents an edge, and the numeric value represents the intensity of that edge. Here is the code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

    data = {
        ('A', 'B'): 0.71,
        ('M', 'B'): 0.67,
        ('N', 'B'): 0.64,
        ('A', 'O'): 0.62,
        ('O', 'B'): 0.60,
        ('N', 'O'): 0.53,
        ('M', 'O'): 0.46,
        ('A', 'N'): 0.18,
        ('M', 'N'): 0.11
    }
    G = nx.Graph()
    for key, value in data.items():
        G.add_edge(*key, weight=value)
    fig, axe = plt.subplots()
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=123456)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, ax=axe)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, ax=axe)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=12, ax=axe)
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight"), ax=axe)

However, I encountered the issue of overlapping nodes. I have attached the output image generated by the code for your reference.

Is there any solution to handle this problem?

your code works fine for me with nx version 3.3 and mpl version 3.8.2, no overlapping

@Stef After updating nx version and mpl versions, now code is correctly working. Thank you
